# tinymce - make url clickable

Tags: javascript, tinymce

```
tinymce.init({
selector: "#texright",
content_css: "content.css",
plugins: ["save link autolink hr advlist lists searchreplace table contextmenu directionality paste code"],
toolbar1: "bold hr save alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify bullist numlist outdent indent link code",
});
```

Is it possible to have url clickable as real hyperlink, for example like in notepad++ - when a hyperlink is pasted or typed - it is automatically clickable.

I visited various pages on SO, tinymce.com etc searching for solution - without success.

Comment: if htttp or https is used with proper URL structure then notepad ++ make url clickable. But what you want to do with tinymce?

Comment: @Abdul, the same thing as in notepad++. When I type or paste an url - it should be clickable.

Comment: visit this url: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/link/

it will might solve your problem.

Comment: @Abdul, as one can see `link` and `autolink` plugins are alreade included in my `init` function, but they do not covert urls to clickable links automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that you have to press Enter after inserting the link. Only then it is converted to a hyperlink instead of text.